# Listening to nested form control value produces an error null is not an object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form and nested a address form within the main form. The thing is that I want to listen to one of the form controls that is nested within the main form. I subscribed to the form control as I normally do with  the controls like,

```
this.myForm.get('addresses.street').valueChanges.subscribe( x=>{
   console.log(x);
})
```

This produces an error ERROR
Error: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.myForm.get('addresses.street').valueChanges')

I have the working code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jncqve?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

it should be just `address`

```
 this.myForm.get('addresses').valueChanges.subscribe( x=>{
      console.log(x);
 })
```

Since the street is a child group of address, whenever street change it will subscribe to this.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bkni7u?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I only have to listen to the control within the nested form and not the whole nested form.